# YouTube iframe inside another iframe doesn't work fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am using YouTube iframe inside another iframe which looks like the snippet below. The problem is, I cannot use fullscreen feature for the video even though I have enabled the attributes required.

if the video doesn't work in the snippet, I have created a fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/uwhg6452/

```html
<iframe class="uvembed114199" frameborder="0" src="https://app.upviral.com/embed/lead/call/ajax/camp/114199/cid/lp114199//widget/iframe/k/0" style="width: 100%; height: 1254px;" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"`  to the outside iframe as well and it solved the problem.